# ログインが必要なWebサイトでのファイルダイアログの制御について

Tags: python, javascript, html, django

開発環境は
サーバOS : Raspberry Pi OS
サーバ側：Python(Django)
クライアント側:HTML+JavaScript

パスワード入力によるログインが必要なWebサイトを作成しています。
一定時間操作が行われなかった場合、強制的にログアウトとする仕様にしています。

Webサイト内では、ファイルのインポート/エクスポートが行える画面があります。
現在、インポート時にファイルダイアログを出しっぱなしにしていても
一定時間操作が行われなかった場合、強制的にログアウトとなります。
その場合、ファイルダイアログが出しっぱなしとなってしまいます。
この動きはおかしいのではないかと思いましたが、一般的にはどのような動作が良いのでしょうか？
(インポートが完了するまでログアウトはしないといった仕様にしていることが多いのでしょうか？)

Comment: その仕様を決めるのが設計、つまりあなたの仕事なわけです。なお今の文言だとアンケートに見えてしまい stackoverflow 的には非推奨ってことになっちゃいます。

Comment: 「インポート時にダイアログ」はファイル選択を行うダイアログですか？であれば、これを (ログアウトがかかるまで) 長時間出しっぱなしにすることが想定している操作でしょうか？ / 「ダイアログが出しっぱなし」と「インポート完了までログアウトしない」で複数の質問がごちゃ混ぜになっている気がします。

Comment: 「ファイルのインポート」というのはブラウザからのファイルアップロードのことで、「ファイルダイアログ」というのは input type="file" がブラウザに表示されてそのボタンをクリックすると表示されるものと理解してますが、違いますか？> 質問者さん

Answer (score 0):

> インポート時にファイルダイアログを出しっぱなしにしていても一定時間操作が行われなかった場合、強制的にログアウトとなります。その場合、ファイルダイアログが出しっぱなしとなってしまいます。この動きはおかしいのではないかと思いましたが、一般的にはどのような動作が良いのでしょうか？

質問者さんの使っている認証システムがどういうものか不明ですが・・・

例えばよくある認証チケットをクッキーに入れてやり取りし、認証チケットには有効期限があって、それが切れた場合とかの話であれば何ともならないはずです。

たとえばユーザーがログインしたあと長時間席を外して認証チケットの有効期限が切れた場合、ブラウザに表示されているのは席を外した時の画面そのままです。ユーザーが席を外している間に、サーバー側で有効期限をチェックして、期限が切れていたら画面を変更するなんてことはできません。

おかしいと思っても何ともならないです。